# Update OTB facets for anonymous user

Tags: mongodb, sitecore-xdb

Using Sitecore 8.2, Im having trouble consistently update email, and name fields for a contact. In MongoDB, I've seen the contacts collection updated with these fields previously with this code but I've just removed all rows from Contacts in  Mongo and executed the code below and there is no new entry in contacts

```
Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(emailAddress);
var currentContact = Tracker.Current.Contact;

var personalFacet = currentContact .GetFacet<Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContactPersonalInfo>("Personal");

personalFacet.FirstName = firstName;

personalFacet.Surname = surName;

XdbContactManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(currentContact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
XdbContactManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(currentContact);
```

with

```
XdbContactManager.FlushContactToXdb(currentContact);
```

Seems to have fixed my issue